# Does the product of two primes only have those primes, itself, and 1 as factors?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Happened to review RSA key generation today, and it has led me to this question. I've tried it with a few but obviously that doesn't make it mathematically proven.

Comment: This is a case of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An integer greater than one is a prime if it has no divisors other than one and itself. Therefore, if $p,q$ are primes, $pq$ has no divisors other than $p$, $q$, and one.

Answer (score 3):

This is trivially true. If $p$ and $q$ are primes, the only way to write them is $p$ and $q$. So $pq$ can only be written as $pq$

Comment: Trivial given a background in mathematical notation! But great point.

Comment: @KamuelaFranco kids in year 9 (which is like 14) learn that prime numbers do not have "factor trees"

Comment: Yes, I am sure I learned that completely out of context to reality in that year or earlier as well. But as is often the case in life, it didn't stick until today when I had one possible application of it brought to light. In any case, it certainly didn't seem trivial to Gauss, who saw fit to prove it as late as the beginning of the 19th century according to another answer here as enlightening as yours has been.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only looking at positive integers, then yes, of course, the product of two positive primes has only $1$, the two primes and itself as divisors.

Call $\sigma_0(n)$ the function that tells you how many positive divisors a positive number $n$ has. Then, if $p$ and $q$ are primes, then $\sigma_0(pq) = 4$ and those four divisors are $1, p, q, pq$. Example: $65 = 5 \times 13$. The only positive divisors are $1, 5, 13, 65$.

If you broaden your view to the negative integers, you can just take the positive divisors and multiply each by $-1$ to get the negative divisors: $-65, -13, -5, -1$.

And if you further broaden your view to a domain in which those numbers are not primes, things get more interesting: $(2 - i)(2 + i)(2 - 3i)(2 + 3i) = 65.$